# Is autonomy or deduction the more primary component of intelligence?

Tags: consciousness, computation, intentionality

I find myself again facing a gap in definitions with a given range of philosophical schools.  So at the risk of "pushing agenda" or "simply requesting opinion" I would like to ask for other ways of looking at this impasse.

I subscribe rather firmly to a psychoanalytic notion of thinking, wherein thought is composed of information, intention and symbolism (captured most clearly via Lacan's three worlds, but going back to Freud's "Ich", "Es" and "Sie" selves, which are moderately oversimplified).  Anything without all three is not thinking.

I understand that the definition comes from a biased field, which is not really even a science by many modern standards, and that cannot presume to define philosophical terms for everyone else.

The specific question is about 'intention'.

> Is there a less "schoolish" tradition in philosophy that captures intention and individual choice as a greater component of intelligence than sheer processing power?  What are other philosophical framings related to this one?

From this point of view my dog has intelligence and my computer doesn't, because the computer only defies me when it has been misinformed, and the dog defies me because he is of a species that has different basic agenda from mine, and on top of that, he makes decisions of his own.

So there is an impasse between this kind of psychology and 'hard' cognitive science.  People from a more mechanical orientation generally end up having a continual disconnect on vocabulary related to thought.  They either have decided that all information processing is intelligence, or generated (to me) odd definitions that prevent computing from being thinking in ad-hoc ways.

At the same time, this kind of thinking attributes intelligence to much more ambiguous objects like a group, a company, or a society, in that the individuals in an environment act as agents of the collective intelligence that only really exists in composite.  (A group's members don't really individually believe the things the group decisively acts on, even in very conforming groups.)

It also includes unconscious, 'primary process' thinking as thinking, in a way that is continually problematic, relative to those oriented toward neurology.  (To me this is the Von Neumann question, and has been resolved -- virtual machines are real, and if we describe our hardware as software, no damage is done -- hardware, software and data are not truly separable to begin with.  But it causes problems, nonetheless.)

So both approaches kind of deviate from common sense.

I also want to make clear that this is not a question about 'free will' vs determinism: In the extreme case, it seems that a species, or even the entire genetic process derives its own direction in a way that changes over time, and is not driven by another deciding force.  Evolution solves problems, it communicates information (via DNA), and it directs itself.  So, by my definition, it is intelligent, even though I can admit that I see it as completely determined.

Comment: It seems like [abductive inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning) might be relevant here...

Comment: But both positions are already 'abductions' from different sets of data, one from what seems to impair human intelligence in coping with the world (the psychoanalytic one), and the other about how impressive computing accomplishments are, and how complex systems' behavior exceeds or 'misinterprets' its planned intent (the cognitive sciences one).  How does one compare them?

Comment: There is some horrible pun buried in there about how mere plausiblity might kidnap more reliable logic...  Abduce is a hideous word.

Comment: I think that the problem arises from your assumption that there is only one "kind/type" of thought.

Comment: I don't think I am being very prescriptive about what kinds of thought there are, only assuming that there is some basic notion where the word is well-defined.  If whether or not animals/computers/institutions 'think' is merely a matter of choice, then we should take Wittgenstein's advice and shut up about it.